# Twitter4j getOAuthRequestToken() Method Raises an ILLEGALSTATEEXCEPTION

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I'm new to twitter4j and i just went through the following tutorial

http://www.java-tutorial.ch/framework/twitter-with-java-tutorial

After this i made some changes to that code according to my need...

In eclipse i have the following directory structure

[image: Eclipse Directory Structure]

The Problem is getOAuthRequestToken() method is raising an exception and is telling me that customer key/secret is not set... But i have set it in that file.... Infact I have set all the properties in twitter4j.properties file....

Can anyone tell me where have i gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add twitter4j.properties to your classpath. Add it to the folder "Java Ressources" for example and your problem will be solved :)